# How to specify theme in Rmarkdown notebook depending on output format?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

How do I tell to knitr to use `theme_classic` if I export my Rmd notebook to PDF and use `dark_theme_gray` from `ggdark` package if I export my Rmd notebook to HTML?

Comment: Do you mean different ggplot themes? Or rmarkdown themes.

Comment: I mean `ggplot2` themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. (Sorry. I had no `ggdark` installed. So I just used `theme_gray` for HTML output). `knitr` provides helper functions to check for `is_html_output` or `is_latex_output`.

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Plot

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()

if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
  p + theme_gray()
} else if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  p + theme_classic()
}
```
````